# How do I give streams better exception messages?

Tags: c++, c++11, std

#### The problem

As of right now, the exception support for streams are terrible. When the Boost.System library was adopted into C++11, one was given the impression that *maybe* exceptions would improve. All the change did was replace `std::exception` with `std::system_error`. While `<system_error>` is a good library on its own for developers, the standard committee and standard library implementors have not taken any steps towards using it to improve exception messages.

To give an idea of how terrible it is, here's a brief summary of what goes down:

- An error occurs.
- `setstate` is used to set `badbit` or `failbit`.
- `clear` is called by `setstate`.
- If exceptions are enabled, `clear` will throw an `ios_base::failure`.

Yes, that means for ALL errors the same useless exception message is thrown. This is specified at the `basic_ios` level, so all derived classes suffer from this issue. The offending quote:

> [iostate.flags]/4 *Effects*: If `((state | (rdbuf() ? goodbit : badbit)) & exceptions()) == 0`, returns. Otherwise, the function
>   throws an object `fail` of class `basic_ios::failure` (27.5.3.1.1),
>   constructed with implementation-defined argument values.

Here's an example of what "implementation-defined argument values" gives us:

```
ios_base::clear: unspecified iostream_category error
```

**Is there an easy fix?**

Neither `Boost.Filesystem` nor `Boost.Iostreams` are replacements for `<iostream>`. The former is a library for portably dealing with a *filesystem* (and is likely to appear in the next revision of C++) while the latter has something to do with..Sources and Sinks. The documentation states that it delegates exceptions to `ios_base::failure` anyways. `Boost.Filesystem` *does* provide `<boost/filesystem/fstream.hpp>` which uses `path` instead of `const char*` arguments to `open()`. It shows an example of how one might inherit from standard library classes:

```
  template < class charT, class traits = std::char_traits<charT> >
  class basic_ifstream : public std::basic_ifstream<charT,traits>
  {
  private: // disallow copying
    basic_ifstream(const basic_ifstream&);
    const basic_ifstream& operator=(const basic_ifstream&);

  public:
    basic_ifstream() {}

    // use two signatures, rather than one signature with default second
    // argument, to workaround VC++ 7.1 bug (ID VSWhidbey 38416)

    explicit basic_ifstream(const path& p)
      : std::basic_ifstream<charT,traits>(p.BOOST_FILESYSTEM_C_STR, std::ios_base::in) {}

    basic_ifstream(const path& p, std::ios_base::openmode mode)
      : std::basic_ifstream<charT,traits>(p.BOOST_FILESYSTEM_C_STR, mode) {}

    void open(const path& p)
      { std::basic_ifstream<charT,traits>::open(p.BOOST_FILESYSTEM_C_STR, std::ios_base::in); }

    void open(const path& p, std::ios_base::openmode mode)
      { std::basic_ifstream<charT,traits>::open(p.BOOST_FILESYSTEM_C_STR, mode); }

    virtual ~basic_ifstream() {}
  };
```

This is a neat trick, except since our offending function is non-virtual and all the way up in `basic_ios`, there's a combinatorial explosion of what we have to reimplement:

[image: iostream inheritance diagram]

I suspect an entire rewrite is needed because simply replacing `clear()` won't be enough. The stream can fail for multiple reasons but there's only *one* type of exception thrown. While `std::system_error` gives us better tools of expressing errors, that doesn't help if, again, there's no way to distinguish the source of the error.

However I'm not a library writer and don't feel like taking on this task. Are there any other options than the ones I listed?

Comment: I do not have an answer for you, but I'd like to say that I do like your question as it is well formed and structured and address a very good topic and issue of concern.

Comment: Well you could start an open source project to write that. But you need to find a project leader if you do not want to be yourself... The nice thing with this is that even if it is a full rewrite, the result would be a drop in replacement provided the new exceptions inherit from the old one.

Comment: I think there is a difference between these io-flags and exception in regards that you have to define a whole code block for exceptions to happen and be caught. In some cases exceptions are slower, but the good thing is you can choose in C++ whether to use them or not. I agree with you that this needs to be improved and I hope the next C++ standard will consider it. And if not maybe explain here, why this implementation.

Comment: Seems you're best workaround is to not use C++ for I/O.

Comment: @Walter well I would say: perhaps the best workaround is not to use iostreams!  You can still use `cstdio` or any library or system calls.

Answer (score 3):

Boost is an open source project so the way I see it there are 2 options:

1. Complain. Either write a bug report or get on the mailing list and suggest an enhancement or both. If the community thinks you have a good point, someone might take it on
2. Do 1, then do something about it. You'll probably get some support from the community. You might no be a library writer, but maybe the people behind boost were not either, until they were.

There is no magic way to fix it, someone has to do the work.